# Is there a open source Android 3D game develop kit?

Tags: android

I found Kilobolt. It seems good to use, but I am not sure if it is open source.

And there is some similar question before, but posted 2 or 3 years ago. I think things have changed?

Comment: Although this is a question asking for tool/lib suggestion, but to me it seems a useful one.

Answer (score 1):

There are few of them out there which are ope source and really good. Couple of them which I have tried and found useful are:

1. Cocos3D for Android
2. AndEngine

These are 2D and 3D game development Library for android

Answer (score 1):

I suggest : libgdx. 
It's the best for me. 
Download from here : [LibGdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of them....

Alien3D

Ardor3D

Cocos3D

These are just some of them...  You might want to check out http://mobilegameengines.com/android/3d_game_engines

(Also I don't believe AndEngine supports 3D games but I may be wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Also jMonkeyEngine: http://jmonkeyengine.org/ although it's not only for Android, but for Java in general.